# Read/Write text file progressbar in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a function which reads a big text file,splits a part(from a given start and end),and save the splitted data into another text file.since the file is too big,i need to add a progressbar when reading the stream and another one when writing the splitted text into the other file.Ps.start and end are given datetime!!

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
{
    while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();

        if (line.IndexOf(start) != -1)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-") + "cut"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
                while (sr.EndOfStream == false && line.IndexOf(end) == -1)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            richTextBox1.Text += "done ..." + "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please expand. Are you talking about silverlight, winforms, WPF? etc.

Comment: The other thing you need to think about is whether you want the progress bar to start at 0 and go to 100, as opposed to a progress bar that cycles around over and over. If so then you need to have a way of working out how many lines the file has so that you can accurately report the progress.

Comment: well for reading it could cycle arround just for showing that the searching is in progress..when (line.IndexOf(start) != -1) is true niw the progress bar should be exact till till it finishes writing.

Comment: i cannot really predict how many lines are there between start and end since it is kind of searching the lines till the requested end appears.or what you think?

Comment: Perhaps what I suggest below would make that unnecessary, rather than the number of lines, how many bytes through the file you are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to work out how long the file is using FileInfo,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
long length = fileInfo.Length;
```

I would suggest you do it like this,

```
private long currentPosition = 0;

private void UpdateProgressBar(int lineLength)
{
    currentPosition += line.Count; // or plus 2 if you need to take into account carriage return
    progressBar.Value = (int)(((decimal)currentPosition / (decimal)length) * (decimal)100);
}

private void CopyFile()
{
    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;

    currentPosition = 0;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            UpdateProgressBar(line.Length);

            if (line.IndexOf(start) != -1)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-") + "cut"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                    while (sr.EndOfStream == false && line.IndexOf(end) == -1)
                    {
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        UpdateProgressBar(line.Length);
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }

                richTextBox1.Text += "done ..." + "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is calculating the percentage of the file that has been read and setting the progress bar to that value. Then you don't have to worry about whether the length is a long, and the progress bar uses int.

If you don't want to truncate the value then do this (casting to an int above will always truncate the decimals, and thus round down),

```
progressBar.Value = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)currentPosition / (decimal)length) * (decimal)100), 0);
```

Is this on a background thread? Don't forget that you will have to call this.Invoke to update the progress bar or else you will get a cross thread exception.

Comment: this seems ok ..but do you think this works only when searching for start and not when writing..or i missed something..

Comment: fileInfo.Length has to be long..and progressBar.Maximum has to be of type int this will not work.

Comment: You can make the minimum 0 and the maximum 100 and do a calculation and round it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Your other comment there - but do you think this works only when searching for start and not .... I don't follow. This should update the progress bar for every line of the input file that is read.

Comment: look there is another line = sr.ReadLine();
inside the streamwriter!!so the progressbar will update before finding start and nomore after.(while reading but not while reading and writing).thanks peter..

Comment: Is this working for you? Please mark as answer, or let me know if not working.

Comment: yes,i have just changed line.count to lineLenght and some times when the file too small,thae progressbar do not load till 100.so i needed to add progressBar1.value = 100; just before richtextbox.text="done"; for the proressbar to complete just after read write has finished.

Comment: the parameter `lineLength` isn't used?